# How to show $\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}=\frac{4\omega^2+3}{13}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I was solving a cubic equation with two different methods and one of the root I got with first method is $\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}$ and with second method I got $\frac{4\omega^2+3}{13}$.

**$\omega$ is the cube root of unity**

If I set one equals another then I got an equality $13=13$ which indicates that they are equal.

$$\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}=\frac{\omega^2}{1-3\omega}$$

After this I think we have to do rationalization kind of thing to the make denominator real but I could not figure out How.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can multiply by the conjugate of the denominator to make it real.

Comment: We get $$\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}=
\frac{1\cdot \omega^2}{(\omega-3\omega^2)\cdot\omega^2}=\frac{\omega^2}{\omega^3-3\omega^4}=\frac{\omega^2}{1-3\omega}$$

Comment: @Jochen Actually that's not what I wanted to show(I have showed that)I wanted to show problem in title of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjugate of $\omega$ is $\omega^2$, so multiply top and bottom by $\omega^2-3\omega$. This gives

$$\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}\cdot\frac{\omega^2-3\omega}{\omega^2-3\omega}$$

$$=\frac{\omega^2-3\omega}{1-3\omega^2-3\omega^4+9}$$

Use $\omega^3=1$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ to give

$$=\frac{\omega^2-3\omega}{1-3(\omega^2+\omega)+9}$$

$$=\frac{\omega^2-3\omega}{13}$$

$-3\omega=3+3\omega^2$ then gives your result.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint : if $\omega$ is cube root of unity, so $\omega^3=1$ put in like below and simplify $$\frac{1}{\omega-3\omega^2}=\frac{\omega^3}{\omega-3\omega^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply by the conjugate of the denominator to make it real, but another approach is:
$(\omega-3\omega^2)(4\omega^2+3)=4\omega^3+3\omega-12\omega-9\omega^2=4-9\omega-9\omega^2=13$
Dividing by $13(\omega-3\omega^2)$ gives the eqn in title.